# Getting variable from private

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a list of playlist titles, count how many playlists there are, and add a windows form button for each playlist.

Add a playlist title to the button.
When button is selected, match button number to playlist... do stuff

```
namespace ClassLibrary6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List<string> IList()  //get title name for playlist
        {
            List<string> iList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var playlist in PluginHelper.DataManager.GetAllPlaylists())
            {
                iList.Add(playlist.Name);
            }
            return iList;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateTheButtons();
        }

        private void CreateTheButtons() //create buttons 
        {
            List<string> hostList = IList();
            int var1 = 0;
            foreach (var playlist in PluginHelper.DataManager.GetAllPlaylists()) //count playlists
            {
                ++var1;                
            }

            myButton[] BooTon = new myButton[var1];  //add button on playlist count
            for (int i = 0; i < BooTon.Length; i++)
            {                 
                BooTon[i] = new myButton();
                BooTon[i].Size = new Size(250, 50);
                BooTon[i].Location = new Point( 0 ,i * 60);
                BooTon[i].Text = (hostList[i]);
                BooTon[i].SetNum1(i);
                BooTon[i].Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
                this.Controls.Add(BooTon[i]);                 
            }
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            myButton btn = sender as myButton;
            List<string> hostList = IList();

            MessageBox.Show(hostList[btn.GetNum1()]); //messagebox selected button playlist title
            //MessageBox.Show(btn.Num1 + ", " + iList[1] + "Button Clicked");
        }
    }

    public class myButton : Button
    {
        private int num1;

        public int GetNum1()
        {
            return num1;
        }

        public void SetNum1(int value)
        {
            num1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I display:

> `MessageBox.Show(hostList[btn.GetNum1()])` outside of the `private void ButtonClick`.

I can't change it to `public` without errors. Is my `get`/`set` right? Would someone mind placing my `MessageBox` outside private but still have it show on the button press please?

If you also have any tips for better practices, please share.

I have googled and searched, but hit a wall. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The so called `private` is an event handler of your buttons, aka what happens when you click on a certain button, means you have to have it there is you want it to be displayed when you click a button

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Please try to explain better.

Comment: There is a great video where [JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/01/jon-skeet-answers-your-questions-irl/?cb=1) explains that it is important to know the language you are working with before you start doing things. There are a lot of things that show that you have no experience in C# and you might need to learn the language first, the get/set is rather Java style at the moment, naming a method `IList()` is confusing, your counting of the items in the list is well overly complicated, list has a property `Count` for it, classnames start with capitals (by convention, not requirement)...

Comment: Your code seems like it should work as I expect it to. What is the issue?

Comment: Sorry, im a noob Im not sure how to explain myself properly. I want to use btn.GetNum1 in another method but am getting inaccessible due to its protection level. I get the feeling im still not making sense. Sorry. I might have to come back when iv learnt the terminology.

Comment: Yeah I agree icepick. but I gotta start somewhere and I struggle to follow tutorials or follow books. Trail and error is best for me. Pick something to do and go for it.

Comment: I didnt thank you for the suggestions last night @icepck. So thank you... The get/set was different, how it is now is what VS recommended lol. And I did try count for my list but admittedly I didnt research it, i was being lazy. The other stuff I did not know. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is on how to access button property from another method, if that is the case, you have to change the scope of the button array.

At the moment the array is created within a method called 'CreateTheButtons', this limits the array's scope within this method, you cannot reference the array outside this method and its associated event listener.

Instead, you can declare the button array on the form level, such as:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       myButton[] BooTon;
       ...
```

change the code in 'CreateTheButtons()' to:

```
        private void CreateTheButtons() //create buttons 
        {
         ...
           BooTon = new new myButton();
         ...
        }
```

from now on, you can call BooTon[i].GetNum1() from other places within Form1.

Answer (score -1):

A wild guess here but can't you do something lile this? just add another function:

```
public void someBtnFunct(object sender) 
{
    myButton btn = sender as myButton;
    List<string> hostList = IList();
    MessageBox.Show(hostList[btn.GetNum1()]); //messagebox selected button playlist title 
    //MessageBox.Show(btn.Num1 + ", " + iList[1] + "Button Clicked");
 }
```

And the call this from wherever you want to, eg:

```
someBtnFunct(BooToo[0]);
```